# Oracle v() vs nv() function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

What is the difference between `v()` and `nv()` functions in oracle apex?

I came across the `nv()` function and the only thing I can get google to spit out is the `nvl()` function.

```
apex_custom_auth.post_login(   
                p_uname      => l_authenticated_username,  
                p_session_id => nv('APP_SESSION'),  
                p_app_page   =>
apex_application.g_flow_id||':'||nvl(apex_application.g_flow_step_id,0));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nv` returns a number rather than a string (so obviously it only works with numeric attributes).  If you use `v` to return numeric values, you can sometimes run into performance issues related to data type conversion.

See [Syntax for referencing item values](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E39147_04/bldapp_item.htm#CEGJAFEA)

Comment: Which also means that we need to explicitly convert date values stored in session state => to_date(:P1_DATE)

Answer (score 4):

It is

> GET_NUMERIC_SESSION_STATE Function
>
> This function returns a numeric value for a numeric item. You can use
>   this function in Oracle Application Express applications wherever you
>   can use PL/SQL or SQL. You can also use the shorthand, function NV, in
>   place of APEX_UTIL.GET_NUMERIC_SESSION_STATE.

See [Oracle Application Express APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b32258/api.htm#CHDBHEAD) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling **APEX_APPLICATION.G_USER** (it shows currently logged user)
you can easily call **v('APP_USER')** so according to me, it's like an evaluator function that provides you a ease to get values of Apex global variables.
So these are equivalent.

```
v('APP_SESSION')
APEX_APPLICATION.get_session_id
```

[Check Oracle APEX global variables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/Global-Variables.htm#AEAPI29544)

`NV('APP_CURRENT_LOGGED_USERS_HIGH)` works with numeric values,(took an example of a user-defined global variable in APEX)